# Proper way to include a module in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, restangular

I'm learning Angular and I'm trying to include Restangular this way:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp',['restangular']);
app.controller('UsersController', ['$scope', function ($scope, Restangular) {
   ...
```

Then I'm using Restangular like this:

```
var data = Restangular.all('someurl');
```

Here I get an error: Restangular is undefined. According to the documentation, this should have been simple:

```
// Add Restangular as a dependency to your app
angular.module('your-app', ['restangular']);

// Inject Restangular into your controller
angular.module('your-app').controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, Restangular) {
  // ...
});
```

However I am unable to get it to work. What gives?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're using the bracket notation for your controller, but you forgot to add Restangular to the list of dependencies:

```
['$scope', 'Restangular', function ($scope, Restangular) {...}]
```

[This article](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05) has more information on Angular and minification. Search for "A note on minification”.

Comment: I tried this also, but this seemed to break something else (a custom filter). I'll try this again and look into it a bit more.

Comment: Ok, this is the correct way to do this, my code is wasn't working for other reasons, so I was asking the wrong questions here really.

Answer (score -3):

That looks correct, just make sure you've added the import of Restangular to your html file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/restangular/1.1.3/restangular.js"></script>
```

They also mention it requires lodash or underscore.js so maybe make sure you're loading those as well